# Mixed symbology for point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

I have a point layer which symbolize trees. This trees has fields `"Specie"` and `"Diameter"` among others. I would like to symbolize them by size depending on the `"Diameter"` but also (at the same time) by colours depending on the `"Specie"`.

So at the end I would have trees on different sizes but also colours. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please read up on `data driven override`.

Comment: Thanks but i dont really understand what do you mean. Sorry and thanks for your answer

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#using-data-defined-override-for-labeling - what works for colour, works for size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Layer Styling panel, select data driven override (yellow highlighted buttons) for diameter and species each. On the screeshots, the procedure for the species/colors is shown, but it works almost exactely the same for diameter/size of the points.

As an alternative, you could consider using Graduated Layer Styling, but than you can just select one field as input.

Thus better use data driven override: select `Data driven override / Assistant`:

[image]

In the dialog that opens, set the source field (here: species), load max./min. values (I created a species field with random values from 1 to 7), than select a color ramp (you can also change it or create a new one, as you wish). That's it. Set a data driven size in the same way and you're done.

[image]

You have different possibilites to adapt everything to your needs. E.g. use QGIS expressions to change let's say a value for diameter to the area of the circle, using the formula/expression  `pi() * ( ("diameter" / 2 )  ^ 2 )`. Use the ε Symbol to open the expression editor for complex operations. You can also select different Scale methods like surface or radius, see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Babel for your answer, the truth is that this solution is very good. Now, I come up with another concern that maybe you'll be able to answer as well. Would it be possible to set up the size of the point in such a way that displays the radius of the circunference depending on the diameter at scale? (I am having perimeter but i can easily transform to radius)

Comment: I added a reply to this question to my answer